# Create a solution which have all the existing projects directly or indirectly under a directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have many Visual Studio C# projects, stored in their own directories.

I would like to create a solution which contains all the projects.

The basic idea I have is to

1. first go to the common ancestor directory of the projects, and use GNU `find` to find all the `.csproj` files recursively under it. Add the pathnames of all the found `.csproj` files into a file. 
   The first step requires me some effort to find how to use `find` to do that.
2. formulate the file into a `.sln` file. The second step is more of a
   problem, because how can I write a `.sln` file for given `.csproj`
   files? For example, I checked at the `.sln` file of an existing
   solution, and couldn't figure out what the numerical strings mean
   and how to generate them.

   ```
   Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
   # Visual Studio 2010
   Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "myProject", "myProject.csproj", "{D36E9F63-37D8-43F3-BF87-EA1F5D31B971}"
   EndProject
   Global
           GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
                   Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
                   Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
           EndGlobalSection
           GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
                   {D36E9F63-37D8-43F3-BF87-EA1F5D31B971}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
                   {D36E9F63-37D8-43F3-BF87-EA1F5D31B971}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
                   {D36E9F63-37D8-43F3-BF87-EA1F5D31B971}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = 
   Release|Any CPU
                   {D36E9F63-37D8-43F3-BF87-EA1F5D31B971}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 =
   Release|Any CPU
           EndGlobalSection
           GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
                   HideSolutionNode = FALSE
           EndGlobalSection
   EndGlobal
   ```

An alternative idea is as following. In Visual Studio 2015, I might create an empty solution, and add the projects to the solution one by one. But there are so many projects, and if in the future there are projects added or removed, I have to create a new solution all over again.

So what shall I do?

Thanks.

Comment: You should really only use solutions to group related projects.  It sounds like you are trying to place ALL your projects in a single solution - which is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I am not asking whether it is a good idea to do that, but how to do that. Since you wonder, my purpose is to find all the references of an identity used across the projects (some projects are libraries, which are used by other projects which are either libraries or applications).

Comment: Those *numerical strings* are your project guids. you can extract all information need for your .sln file from your .csproj files.

Comment: ... and since your google-foo seems to be a little weak: [Solution (.Sln) File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps you should ask for a method to "find all the references of an identity used across the projects". You've shown what you are considering, there may be alternatives.